# How can I populate data in Dropdown Using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

```
  my Jquery code
 ("#<%=cboBranch.ClientID%>").append($("<option></option>").attr("value",valueData1).text(Data1))

 my asp code
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cboBranch" runat="server" class="medium" >
```

How can I do it? Its not working

Comment: Your JQuery code looks fine; the problem must be something else you're not showing here (eg, script executing before HTML is loaded).  Can you provide a short, self-contained, compilable example?  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Do you want to fill dropdown with JSON data?

Comment: Yes, I done already the JSON and I dont know how to populate it in dropdown. This is a usercontrol. Can you show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looping the data?

```
// clear dropdown
    $("#<%=cboBranch.ClientID%>").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        $("#<%=cboBranch.ClientID%>").append(
              $("<option></option>").val(item.Id).html(item.Name);
        );
    });
```

Read [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx)

Comment: It didnt work, I think the problem is this is not a page this is a usercontrol in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

supposing `result` is your JSON data then do something like this

```
$.each(result, function() {
    options.append($("<option />").val(this.Value).text(this.Name));
```